# why is_base_of fails when both are just plain char type

Tags: c++

Do you see why the static_assert fail:

```
template <typename T>
void 
foo(const T &c)
{

    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, char>::value, "T must be char");  // Fails !

}

int main()
{
    char c = 'a';

    foo<char>(c);

    return 0;
}
```

I swapped T and "char", still fails.

Comment: maybe because `char` is not a class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) for `std::is_base_of` states:

> If Derived is derived from Base or if both are the same non-union
>   class, provides the member constant value equal to true. Otherwise
>   value is false.

But `char` is not a class : it is a primitive type, so this is the expected result.

Comment: oh, ok, then how do I restrict that the type T must be char?

Comment: Why put a template in the first place ? Just declare a function that takes a char, no ?

Comment: The real use case is complex, I need to make a template function which takes several types including char.

Comment: Do you need *several types*? Or *any* type that inherits from a particular base plus `char`? If it is *several* in general, you should control what types are specifically used.

Comment: Yes, it is char with other types which are derived from same type.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to consider adding additional checks:

```
template <typename T> void foo(const T &c) 
{
    static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<T, char>::value || std::is_same<T, char>::value, 
            "T must be char");

}
```

But if you are only concerned about chars, then you might as well do:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<T, char>::value, "T must be char");
```

Also consider `is_fundamental`, and `is_convertible` for more complex assertions.