# Wildcard for C++ concepts saying "accepting anything for this template argument"

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to allow a `concept` with *template arguments*, to be ok with any template parameter provided?

I.e. some kind of *wildcard magic* for template argument placeholder?

**A usage example:**

```
template<class Me, class TestAgainst>
concept derived_from_or_same_as = 
    std::same_as<Me, TestAgainst> ||
    std::derived_from<Me, TestAgainst>;
```

Above is needed because unfortunately *primitive types* [behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986784/why-is-base-of-fails-when-both-are-just-plain-char-type) than *class types* for `is_base_of` and `derived_from`.

Now we can define a *Pair* `concept` that checks the provided types:

```
template<class P, class First, class Second>
concept Pair = requires(P p) {
    requires derived_from_or_same_as<decltype(p.first), First>;
    requires derived_from_or_same_as<decltype(p.second), Second>;
};
```

**Use case [a] - accept any valid pair of *As* or sub-type of *As*:**

```
// this works well
void doWithPairOfA(const Pair<A, A> auto& p) { /* */ }
```

**Use case [b] - accept any valid pair, no restrictions on the inner types:**

```
// this is *pseudo code* as Pair<auto, auto> is not allowed
void doWithAnyPair(const Pair<auto, auto> auto& p) { /* */ }
```

Unfortunately, [auto is not allowed as template argument placeholder in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358154/auto-as-a-template-argument-placeholder-for-a-function-parameter).

So `Pair<auto, auto>` is not the solution for now.

---

Other languages allow such a syntax in a way, though not with the same exact semantics and meaning as requested here, but the usage looks quite similar.

**Python:**

```
// Any as wildcard
foo(lst: List[Any]) -> List[str]
```

**Java:**

```
// '?' as wildcard
List<String> foo(List<?> lst)
```

---

The pre C++20 syntax would look something like<sup>1</sup>:

**Use case [a] - *trying* to accept any valid pair of *As* or sub-type of *As*:**

```
// not as good as with concepts above, this allows only "pair" of A and A
// **but rejects sub-types of A, which is not good**
// and there is no check that this is actually a pair (can be added with SFINAE)
template<template<class, class> typename PAIR>
void doWithPairOfA(const PAIR<A, A>& p) { /* */ }
```

**Use case [b] - accept any valid pair, no restrictions on the inner types:**

```
// not as good as we would wish - we do allow any kind of "pair"
// but there is no check that this is actually a pair (can be added with SFINAE)
template<template<class, class> typename PAIR, typename ANY1, typename ANY2>
void doWithAnyPair(const PAIR<ANY1, ANY2>& p) { /* */ }
```

[Pre C++20 code](https://godbolt.org/z/KrKnyT)

**Can concepts present a better solution?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Related question (pre C++20) on templates: [Templates accepting “anything” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127137/)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve ***wildcard behavior*** by modifying the *Pair* `concept` to accept and check a tag type *Any*.

Let's first declare *Any* as a tag class, no need to implement it.

```
class Any;
```

Now we can create a ***type_matches*** `concept` to check if a type *T* matches a given type *A*, with the following rules:

***T* matches *A***

- if *A* is *Any*
  -- or --
- if *T*==*A* or if *T* is derived from *A*

As noted in the question, the check for *T*==*A* or *T* is derived from *A* can be made for *class types* just with `std::derived_from` however *primitive types* require adding the test for `std::same_as`.

**The wildcard match would be achieved with the following code:**

```
template<class Me, class TestAgainst>
concept type_matches =
    std::same_as<TestAgainst, Any> ||
    std::same_as<Me, TestAgainst>  ||
    std::derived_from<Me, TestAgainst>;
```

**The *Pair* concept would be modified to:**

```
template<class P, class First, class Second>
concept Pair = requires(P p) {
    requires type_matches<decltype(p.first), First>;
    requires type_matches<decltype(p.second), Second>;
};
```

The code can allow now both required use cases.

**Use case [a] - accept any valid pair of *As* or sub-type of *As*:**

```
// can be called with a Pair of As or sub-type of As
void doWithPairOfA(const Pair<A, A> auto& p) { /* */ }
```

**Use case [b] - accept any valid pair, no restrictions on the inner types:**

```
void doWithAnyPair(const Pair<Any, Any> auto& p) { /* */ }
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/higX9f

Comment: Same change you made to `type_matches` applies equally to `Pair`: `concept Pair = type_matches<typename P::first_type, First> && type_matches<typename P::second_type, Second>;`

Comment: @Barry I prefer not to require having `first_type` and `second_type` thus to a allow user defined pair with only `first` and `second`. But I thought `requires requires` is a distinguished part of C++20...

Comment: Hm? There's no `requires requires` in your solution?

Comment: is it required?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.